# Definition of non-degenerate metric tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, metric-tensor, definition

We know that a metric has a property which is called [non-degeneracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_form). I was searching for what does that mean and saw it associated with the fact that $det(g_{\mu\nu})\neq0$. How does this relate to that?

Comment: The question is not clear. Is det$\ne0$ not the **definition** of non-degeneracy? Do you know a different definition and you search for a proof that the two are equivalent?

Comment: How are both definitions related? No proof is needed just conceptual relation will do it.

Comment: They are related in the same sense that the sentence "two times three is six" is related to the statement $2\times3=6$. It's the same statement, one in English, the other in algebraic notation.

Comment: Oh, this is not what I meant. So, I guess better said how is does the equivalence hold? I guess I will have to check its proof after all. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- A degenerate matrix is a matrix whose rank is smaller than its dimension.

2- A singular (non-invertible) matrix is one that has a vanishing determinant.

Equivalence of the two : A matrix whose rank is smaller than it's dimension when diagonalized will have at least one zero eigenvalue, and consequently a vanishing determinant.

Comment: I have never heard this definition of degenerate matrix.  The identity matrix has only one eigenvalue (which is 1)  and it corresponds to all the vectors (every vector is an eigenvector of the identity). Is the identity degenerate?

Comment: You are correct, since I cannot delete an accepted answer I'll edit it

Comment: Does non degenerate metric here has anything to do with the fact that all the eigenvalues of the metric are different. Or is the word non degenerate does not mean that here

Comment: I have a problem with this definition since all degenerate matrix cannot be diagonalize
For metric this work since a metric is always given by a SYMMETRIC matrix

Comment: @BaptisteBermond Diagonalizable matrices are dense in the space of all square matrices of a given type, so this line of thought can be made rigorous by a continuity argument.

Comment: @BenceRacskó I totally agree but I guess it should be stressed out more clearly


Even though for Metric this is not relevant since   every real symmetric matrix can be diagonalized

Answer (score 7):

If $\text{det } g = 0$, then $\text{ker }  g \neq \{\vec{0}\}$, ie there is some vector $X \in \text{ker } g$,  such that $g(X,\ast) $ gives zero 1-form, so $g(X,Y)=0 $ for any $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/160882/224026

see also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor:
" From the coordinate-independent point of view, a metric tensor is defined to be a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form on each tangent space that varies smoothly from point to point. "

Comment: Does non degenerate metric here has anything to do with the fact that all the eigenvalues of the metric are different. Or is the word non degenerate does not mean that here

Comment: @Shashaank: a degenerate bilinear form f(x,y) has the property that the map f_v: V -> V* with f_v = f(v, . ) is not an isomorphism a.k.a. at least one of the eigenvalues of this linear map is zero.

Answer (score 1):

That $\det g \neq 0$ can be used as the definition of what it means for a metric $g$ to be non-degenerate. As noticed in another answer, an alternative definition is that $g$ has full rank. These two definitions are equivalent by the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

I don't agree with the "when diagonalized" part of the accepted answer (I can't comment unfortunately). The matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$ has rank smaller than its dimension but cannot be diagonalized. It does have a zero eigenvalue so it is not invertible. I believe the relevant result to quote here is the rank-nullity theorem: the rank plus the dimension of the kernel equals the size of the matrix. So when a matrix is degenerate, the kernel is not empty, so there is a zero eigenvalue, so the matrix is not invertible, and vice versa.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/364751)